# mean value theorem applications

Tags: calculus, intuition

1. it is said that the mean value theorem prove that the graph between $[a,b]$ has a point where it is equal to the average change of the graph, (sorry for not being accurate) is there more information about this or a proof?
2. How does it help to find the error in the Taylor series?

Comment: Are you asking for help with the proof or understanding the concept?

Comment: @copper.hat with the concept, no formalization is needed

Comment: Are you familiar with Rolle's theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem)?

Answer (score 0):

The theorem (from when I studied in England) that is usually proved before the MVT - is Rolle's theorem. This states that if a real-valued function $f$ is continuous on a closed interval (say $[a,b]$) and  differentiable on $(a,b)$, then (if $f(a)=f(b)=0$) there is some $d$ such that $a<d<b$ and $f'(d)=0$. Call this theorem $1$.

The M.V.T. states that if a real-valued function $g$ is continuous on a closed interval (say $[a,b]$) and  differentiable on $(a,b)$, then for some $d'$ such that $a<d'<b$ we must have $g'(d')=\frac{1}{b-a}(g(b)-g(a))$.

Assuming Theorem $1$ is true, can you deduce the M.V.T. from this theorem? This would help in understanding the M.V.T.